# Bootstrap 3 carousel showing blank slide at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is interesting. I have a carousel on the homepage and a carousel on an internal page. Both codes are exactly the same, but for some reason, the internal page carousel shows a blank slide at the end, then goes to a height of 10px and starts the slideshow over (at 10px still). The homepage carousel works perfectly.

Here is the code for both of the carousels

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" style="max-height: 481px;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="carousel-inner" style="overflow: inherit;">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://example.com/image1.png">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://example.com/image2.png">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I thought that maybe it was a conflicting "ID" error, so I changed the ID on the internal page carousel and it did nothing.

Homepage template code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php

if (is_front_page() ) {

?> 
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" style="max-height: 481px;overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="carousel-inner" style="overflow: inherit;">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://example.com/image1.png">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://example.com/image2.png">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<?php } else { } ?>


<div class="row main-content homepage">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">test
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">test    
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">test
</div>
</div></div></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Internal page code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>



<div class="row main-content">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>



<?php if (!is_front_page() ) { ?>   <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>  <?php } else {} ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>



<?php endwhile; else: ?>



    <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>



<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div><!-- end row -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: where is the carousel in your internal page code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it is within the page content in the backend of WordPress. Maybe that is what's causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

koala_dev's comment made me realize that it may be something wrong with the way WordPress processes the content loop. That is what messed up my carousel. I created a new internal template for this specific page and transferred my carousel to that. It works fine now. Thanks for reading.